# swf sending servlet doesn't work on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jsp, servlets, flash

im trying to render the swf on jsp page
i can show local files "waf.swf" but whenever i use the servlet address it fails on IE but works on firefox

this is the servlet code

```
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
response.setContentType("application/x-shockwave-flash");
response.setContentLength(length);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"" );
response.setHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
byte[] bbuf = new byte[1024];
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(bbuf)) != -1))
  out.write(bbuf,0,length);

in.close();
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the `Content-Length` is **correct** on the exact bit. For testing purposes you can outcomment it. The application can only not calculate anymore how long it will take before the loading is finished, but it should work. If the content length was wrong, then either the browser would expect more bytes to come and is thus waiting (when content length is bigger than actual file length), or the browser will abort the download and end up with an incomplete flash file (when content length is smaller than actual file length).

The other suspect thing is the `Content-Disposition` header. You didn't explicitly set it to `inline`. You never knows with IE, so try to set it explicitly to `inline` or just outcomment it for testing purposes.

By the way, the `DataInputStream` is superfluous here. You didn't take benefit of any of its methods. Just get rid it and stick to `FileInputStream`. Or, to improve performance a bit more, wrap with `BufferedInputStream` instead (and do the same with `BufferedOutputStream` for the response).

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything you offered. It didn't help.
I tried changing the header cache to:

```
response.setHeader("cache-control", "must-revalidate");
```

i have absolutely no idea why, but it finally works on IE.

thanks !!